# How to block the triggering of a link if I click on its internal element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I have a div that is inside an "a" tag (Link in next.js), and there is also a "like" div inside it. If I click anywhere in the div, I want it to take me where the "a" tag points. However, if I click on the "like" div, I don't want it to take me anywhere; instead, I want a JavaScript script to be triggered.

How to do this? Is there any other way? How should it look to be both functional and SEO-friendly?

On Twitter, there's something similar: the entire "tweet" is clickable and takes you to another page, whereas buttons like "like" work as they should, and that's the effect I want to achieve.

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'

interface LikeTypes {
    likes:number
}

function LikeCard({likes}:LikeTypes ) {

    const likeButtonClicked= () => {

      };
    

  return (
    <div className='flex justify-center items-center ' onClick={(e) => { e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation(); likeButtonClicked(); }}>❤ {likes}</div>
  )
}

export default LikeCard
```

i tried use
`e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();`
but is not working.

part of outside component wraping LikeCard

```
    <Link href={href}>
                  <LikeCard likes={likes}/>
    </Link>
```

Comment: `I have a div that is inside an "a" tag` just FYI, that's not valid HTML. You cannot place a block-level element inside an inline element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preventDefault` should work

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
  Post: <button>Like</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the two approaches here.

1. with the event object passed to the event handler.

   function someFunction (event) {

   ```
   event.preventDefault();
   ```

   }

   this is stop the browsers default behavior.
2. Secondly with `href="javascript:void(0)"`